# .Net Core Delete uploaded Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am using ASP.NET Core to upload files to my database.
Where I have two database, one for the create and for the files.
My code looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Name,Email,Job Title,ICollection<IFormFile> uploads, Track track)
      {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(track);

                // Uploading files for the Request Database
                foreach (var upload in uploads)
                {
                    if (upload.Length > 0)
                    {
                        // Getting file into buffer.
                        byte[] buffer = null;
                        using (var stream = upload.OpenReadStream())
                        {
                            buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
                            stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                        }
                        // Converting buffer into base64 code.
                        string base64FileRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
                        // Saving it into database.
                        _context.Upload.Add(new Request()
                        {
                            UploadName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"), Request.FileName),
                            Uploadcode = base64FileRepresentation,
                            TrackID = track.ID,
                        });
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    }
                }
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(track);
        }
```

In the Edit page, I want to have a button to delete the file that was uploaded to the Track. I have tried to change the delete action from the Controller to the following code, but it didn't work:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteRequest")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteRequest(int id)
    {
        var x= await _context.Upload.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UploadID == id);
        _context.Upload.Remove(x);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

My view Code

```
<a asp-action="DeleteRequest"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:red;"></span></a>
```

when I click it, it takes me to empty page with this URL:
localhost:44444/Tracks/DeleteRequest

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I don't get an error, It just do nothing

Comment: can you please check on SQL profiler / DB that this record is delete or not or some error in query

Comment: Also your are not checkingnull case for your single or default statement .

Comment: I have checked my SQL db and the record was not deleted.

Comment: so first we need to check why that is not happening

Comment: I am using this code for the delete on the view

`<a asp-action="DeleteRequest"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:red;"></span></a>`

when clicked I takes me to localhost:44444/Tracks/DeleteRequest

Comment: i think you have to use TrackId  is this your primary key ? if yes i  updated my answer debug and see if the breakpoint hit insise x!=null which means that what are you deleting s actually present

Comment: My primary key is the UploadID, while the TrackID is a foreign key.

Comment: I have delete the 
`    [HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteRequest")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` and now change the code now it redierct me to the index page without changing anything in the database

Comment: ok I updated it . Can you debug are you getting one record in you x  variable ?

Comment: I debugged, the x variable is null

Comment: I updated my answer can you change your html like that . i think your controller is not hitting . so apply break point on delete after changing this . please udate the controller name in ay answrr posted

Comment: your x is null because yout Id is =0 . Your are not passing it from your html .

Comment: I just added the route id to my html before ask, and it x is still null

Comment: and do you get value of Id in the controller ?

Comment: and if yes does this Id is present in the database . ?

Comment: I don't need to add the asp-controller to the html, I just needed the asp-route-id .. and the record is delete from the database.

Comment: yes but it is more clear if you mark it optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a asp-action="DeleteRequest"   asp-controller="UpdatYourControllerName"
   asp-route-id="@model.UploadId"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:red;"></span></a>
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteRequest(int id)
{
   // here debug the id you passed is actually present in db 
    var x= await _context.Upload.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UploadID  == id);
    if(x!=null)
    {
    _context.Upload.Remove(x);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```